# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'

Tags: flutter

I have having 3 error about the object cant be assigned to parameter including int, string and double . I'm trying to fetch data to create a chart-bar to display and process the data.it fetches from another widget called Transaction.[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:personal_expenses_app/model/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:personal_expenses_app/widgets/chart_bar.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final List<Transaction> recentTransactions;

  Chart(this.recentTransactions);
 

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupTransactionValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      var totalsum = 0.0;

      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalsum = totalsum + recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }

      // print(DateFormat.E().format(weekDay));
      // print(totalsum);

      return {
        'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
        'amount': totalsum
      };
    }).toList();
  }

  double get totalSpending {
    return groupTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['amount'];                         // error  item['amount']
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        children: groupTransactionValues.map((data) {
          return Chartbar(data['day'], data['amount'],        //error data['day'],data['amount']
              (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you will need to cast to a specific type... e.g String , int
item['amount'] as int/double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` here is a `Map<String, Object>`.

```
    return groupTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + item['amount'];                         // error  item['amount']
    });
```

That means `item['amount']` is of type Object, which cannot be used with the + operator, which expects a num type. You are getting the error in the other line for similar reasons.

You can either manually cast all usages of the elements of `groupTransactionValues` to the appropriate types, like so

```
return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
```

or you could change the type of the map to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> get groupTransactionValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is hidden in your code itself. Convert the object to a double.

```
// replace data['amount'] with following
(data['amount'] as double)
```